# ValueError: Could not convert string to float: "nbformat":4

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, glob

After some long calculation, I've got files which contain following strings.

(Each string is separated with "\t" and has "\n" at the end of the each line.)

```
0.0000008375000 829.685601736   555.939928236
0.0000008376000 829.511081539   555.889353246
0.0000008377000 829.336613968   555.838785601
0.0000008378000 829.162199002   555.7882253
0.0000008379000 828.987836621   555.737672342
0.0000008380000 828.813526805   555.687126727
0.0000008381000 828.639269533   555.636588453
```

Then I tried to plot these files. (The file's name is starting with P.)

```
fList = np.array(gl.glob("P*"))
for i in fList:
    f = open(i, "r")
    data = f.read()
    data = data.replace("\n", "\t")
    data = np.array(data.split("\t"))[:-1].reshape(-1,3)
    plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], label=i)
```

Then I ended up with following error.

(Error pointer indicates this happened at the line ***plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], label=i)***)

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "nbformat": 4,
```

I've looked up some other tutorials or walkthroughs but unfortunately, could not understand how to fix this issue. Any help or advice would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use numpy to read in the file into three arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob

fList = glob("P*")
for i in fList:
    x,y,z = np.loadtxt(i, unpack=True)
    plt.plot(x,y, label=i)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Or into a single array for that matter `data = np.loadtxt(i)`

Comment: Thank you ImportanceOfBeingEmest and jadsq!
I found out the problem was file name itself :(.
Codes are just working fine. I have changed file names to explicitly have unique names so that it won't interfere any operation.

Comment: Oh, thank you for ur kind updating. I thought I'd accept the answer, which was apparently not.